# UIAlertView without any buttons

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uialertview

I wanted to know whether the following code is okay or not. I am trying to dismiss the alertView automatically after 2 seconds (and without any buttons in the alertView) from the "timedAlert" method.

```
    //this is in another method  
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Login successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [self timedAlert];
}

-(void)timedAlert
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert:) withObject:alert afterDelay:2];
}

-(void)dismissAlert:(UIAlertView *) alertView
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:nil animated:YES];
}
```

If the cancelButton of the alertView is set to "nil", how will the "[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];" thing work??? I tried making the cancelButton "nil" and it worked, but cant figure out how....

P.S: I call the timedAlert method from another

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, your code is fine. You can read a more detailed explanation here: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/uialertview-without-buttons-please-wait-dialog.html

Comment: thanks! But i still get how the dismissWithClickedBittonIndex works  fine when there are no buttons in the alertView.. Especially why the button index is accepted... Please help!

Comment: I don't really understand what is your question. In the dismissWithClickedBittonIndex method, the button index is optional. If you pass nil (or 0), than the alert simply dismiss.

Comment: okay. Thanks for your help! Thats what i wanted to know... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, and you should have no problems. I have done this in one of my previous apps. The button is not displayed because the title is nil but I think the instance of the button still exists. Put a breakpoint before closing your alert and take a look at the alert variable, and check to see if there is a buttons array or something, that should tell you how that works.

Comment: theres also NSInteger values reading -1 for cancel button, default button, and first other button.. Thats it right? Thats because the dismissWithClickedButtonIndex accepts the nil value for index?????

Comment: i also see a "_dismissButtonIndex" field in it reading 0 value! I hope that says it all! Am I correct?

Answer (score 5):

First let me say it would be better if you handle this with a custom view, but with that said the problem looks to be with

```
[alert release];
```

You are releasing the object before you are done with it (I am surprise it does not crash).

Do something like this

```
// other code
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Login successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert:) withObject:alert afterDelay:3.0f];
}

-(void)dismissAlert:(UIAlertView *) alertView
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:nil animated:YES];
    [alertView release];
}
```

Comment: It wont crash as the [alert show] retains the object and the 'alert' variable still just points at it. The modified code in this answer is OK, but the [alert release] can be left in the code after the [self performSelector....] and removed from the dismissAlert view. Or just move to ARC now to get rid of all this messiness.